# Combining variables into differentials?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, physics, classical-mechanics

While studying a practice problem for a classical mechanics class, I encountered the following expressions in the solution given by my instructor:

Having derived an equation for the upward vertical motion of a projectile (including drag) with gravitational acceleration *g*, velocity *v*, & proportionality constant *k*:
$$\frac{dv}{dt}=-g-kv^2$$
My instructor then takes the following steps:
$$v\frac{dv}{dt}=-(g+kv^2)v$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{dv^2}{dt}=-(g+kv^2)\frac{dy}{dt}$$

My confusion is centered on the left-hand side of the last expression; I've never seen a variable seemingly "absorbed" into a differential before. Is there a rule or theorem for this, or am I missing something obvious?

*(Many thanks in advance for any help you can offer!)*

Comment: It's not absorbed.
It just uses the fact that for a differentiable function $f$, one has $(f^2)' = 2f f'$.
Apply it to $f = v$.